# GCM Push notifications with Titanium

Tags: android, push-notification, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

**Background info:**

- I need to use GCM push notifications in Titanium project. I tried using https://github.com/morinel/gcmpush module, but it doesn't suffice my needs as I need to show the custom layout notifications. I built the layout for custom notification in my Titanium project - success. But, this module overrides the custom layout notifications and shows it's own.
- We are using AWS server where we are sending the notifications.

**Issues:** 
- Receive a push notification from GCM.
- Show the notification in the custom layout that I built.

I have been facing this issue for long. Is there any module/any other way that can help me achieving the solution?

I have tried various modules but did not work. Maybe I have missed anything to try?

Maybe I should connect my AWS server to use Arrow Push notifications? If that can be a solution, how?

Can anybody please enlighten me on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of the most feature rich push notification modules out there, right now, is [Ti.Goosh](https://github.com/caffeinalab/ti.goosh). I recommend using this module.

It allows for a lot of customisation.

Next to that, Appcelerator offers some options to make custom notifications locally. Look at the [Docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Notification) for more info

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

Android client: Ti.Goosh

Android backend: FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging from Google, this also supports browser notifcations in case you expand your platform once...)

IOS client: Default Appcelerator registration, see docs

IOS backend: Default where you stream the notifications to APNS

Take a look at FCM, GCM is deprecating in the future so it's not worth it implementing it now.